# VBA Dual split array values using 2 delimited characters

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In VBA, I'm trying to Split the below sample string in arrays using a char # first and again split the value in each array location using the char :, how can we achieve it.

category:agenda#construct:area graph#ink_ratio_bus:#has_image:#image_size:#has_icons:n#color_type:#has_cartoon:#has_three_d:#has_shading:#shape:#has_graphs:#has_tables:#sid:0003#parent:amod_test#parent_sid:#node:#theme:default

I tried the following but null value creates error in this function

```
  Dim subVals() 
  subVals = Split(oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "#")
                    cmbConstruct.Value = Right(subVals(1), Len(Left(subVals(1), 10)))
                    cmbInk.Value = Right(subVals(2), Len(Left(subVals(2), 6)))
                    cmbImages.Value = Right(subVals(3), Len(Left(subVals(3), 1)))
                    cmbImageSize.Value = Right(subVals(4), Len(Left(subVals(4), 1)))
```

Comment: Nest the Splits?

Comment: Can you show us how the string you posted have to be split? I mean, what to return a code doing what you need? To extract the values of all elements separated by "#", if they are also separated by ":"? Are there other requests than "construct", "image", "image_size" and "ink". Even if I do not understand where from the last parameter should be extracted... From "color_type"?

Answer (score 1):

Hy maybe this would help :)

```
Sub Test()

Dim str As String
str = "category:agenda#construct:area graph#ink_ratio_bus:#has_image:#image_size:#has_icons:n#color_type:#has_cartoon:#has_three_d:#has_shading:#shape:#has_graphs:#has_tables:#sid:0003#parent:amod_test#parent_sid:#node:#theme:default"

Dim key As String, value As String
Dim keyValuePair As Variant
Dim arr As Variant

arr = Split(str, "#")
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
    keyValuePair = Split(arr(i), ":")
    key = keyValuePair(0)
    value = keyValuePair(1)
    Debug.Print key & "-" & value
Next i



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks folks! I found the solution for this as follows:
replace both the delimiters into one, then split with that one delimiter and take only the alternate odd values from the array.

```
NewString = Replace(oldString, ":", "#")
subVals = Split(NewString, "#")
```

take only odd values 1,3,5 etc. from array